# Set serial port flow control lines from bash script?

Tags: linux, bash, serial-port, flow-control

Is it possible to manually control the handshaking/flow control lines of a serial port from a bash script?  I'm referring to RTS, CTS, DTR and DSR.  I don't want to enable automatic flow control, but manually manipulate these signals.  In my application, those lines control LEDs.
I've seen C code to do this using IOCtl(), but am wondering if it is possible via bash?

Answer (score 0):

There were no responses here and I couldn't find anything else on the web.  So I decided to write my own C program I could call from bash.  It was actually quite simple to control the handshaking lines via C - just an open() and a couple of ioctl() calls.  See https://www.cmrr.umn.edu/~strupp/serial.html#5_1 if you are interested in the details.